# Show source file of objects in Chrome developer tools

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-developer-tools

When I use the React Developer Tools, I notice that it can show me the source code of the selected component. It's the button on the upper right corner of the Components panel.

[image: View source button in React Developer Tools]

When I click this button, it opens the source file in the Sources panel.

I'm writing a developer tool myself and I want to do something similar to this. How does the React Developer Tools do it? I didn't see any API in the documentation to do this sort of thing.

Comment: It sets its own `__REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__`, you can check the source code for this button and see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @wOxxOm's comment, I was able to find the source code of this button. Turns out we just need to call `chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval('window.inspect(...)')` passing the object that represents the component. Chrome/Edge will take care of find the source code and show it in the Sources panel.